# What are some functions where the derivative is (non-trivially) easier to compute than the original?

Tags: calculus

For example, the derivative of $ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$, which is much easier to compute than trying to find $ln(x)$.  Another example is the inverse trig functions.  I believe the same applies for the inverse hyperbolic trig functions as well, but I haven't learned those yet.  What are some other examples of this?

Comment: Just because I'm ignorant, in what way is $1/x$ easier to compute? For rational numbers sure but is $1/e$ easier to compute than $\ln e$?

Comment: Typically, I would consider 1/x easier than ln x, although you've given a counter example.  For example, 1/2 vs ln 2.  I guess I should clarify that I'm mostly concerned with rational numbers.

Comment: Maybe just try getting a hold of a table of integrals, and pick out some of the more interesting entries :)

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked at a table of derivatives but didn't think to check a table of integrals.  Going off this very basic table I have, I did find the integral of a^x to be interesting, so that's another one for me to work with.  I'll have to see if I can find some more expansive tables.

Answer (score 5):

A way of making this rigorous is to ask what transcendental functions have algebraic derivatives. That includes your examples.

Another way to approach this is to ask what non elementary functions have elementary derivatives. This includes things like $x \mapsto \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$ or anything like this. I'm sure you can come up with examples.

Comment: "What transcendental functions have algebraic derivatives?" is a better way of phrasing my question, thank you.  I looked up the symbol ↦ and saw that it means "mapped to", so would saying  x↦y be similar to saying f(x)=y?

Comment: @Walker23 Yup that's exactly what it means. That notation is particularly useful for when there are multiple variables and it's ambiguous what is mapping to what. For example if you have the function $f=x^2+y$. You can consider $(x,y) \mapsto x^2+y$ or $x \mapsto x^2+ y$. The first is multivariate and the second holds $y$ constant.